# How to place start edge of EditText in center horizontal of screen?

Tags: java, android

I need and I can't find solution for placing EditText element from center of horizontal line in relative layout? Like android:layout_alignParentRight="true", I would need something like layout_alignParentCenterHorizontal. Is there something like that? thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create an invisible, minimum width item centered horizontally, and then place my EditText relative to that. Use INVISIBLE instead of GONE for the visibility property for this to work.
e.g.

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/centerLine"
   android:layout_width="1dip"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:visibility="invisible"
   />

<EditText
   ...
   android:layout_toRightOf="@id/centerLine"
   ...
   />
```

Comment: This is good idea, but I have to change it to:
     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/centerLine"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

Comment: Ah, yes I missed the centering from the example code. Not sure why you'd have to reduce the height though.

Comment: Because it was expanding all over my Relative layout over height, and other elements wasn't visible.